# how to make persistent connections to memcached server using xmemcached or spymemcached

Tags: java, memcached, spymemcached, persistent-connection, xmemcached

How can we use persistent connections to memcached servers using xmemcached or spymemcached?
I am presently using xmemcached.

```
MemcachedClientBuilder builder = new XMemcachedClientBuilder(
    AddrUtil.getAddresses(
        "127.0.0.1:11211 127.0.0.1:11311" 
    )
);
builder.setConnectionPoolSize(5);
```

With this code I tried to create connection pool and I used ss command to watch the connections being made. However, I can see that when program terminates connections go to time-wait state and next time I run it, more connections are created. So this is not working. What am I missing? Or what can be done in this case? Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In spymemcached all connections are persistent. The reason that your socket are in time-wait state after the program terminates is likely because you have to call some sort of shutdown() function to actually close the sockets. At least this is the case in spymemcached. I would also bet that this is the case in xmemcached.

Comment: yes, i did call the shutdown function. But without that program waits endlessly. Suppose, I make a web call, what will happen to response?

Comment: you are correct. I ran it as a web application in a servlet contained in jetty server and it is showing me persistent connections. Thanks a lot for helping out